# regular expression for 5 digit number excluding '00000'

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

i need to have a regular expression which accept atleast 1 digit number and maximum 5 digit number and if user enter zero in the following fashion like '00','000','0000','00000' then expression should reject such inputs.
currently, i am using ^[0-9]{1,5}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[1-9].*)[0-9]{1,5}$
```

Uses a lookahead assertion to make sure there's at least one nonzero digit.  If there is one, then the rest of the expression only matches if there's between 1 and 5 digits.  Both conditions have to be met, or the expression won't match.

Agreed, though, that if you're trying to match a *number*, as opposed to a string of digits (like a ZIP code), it'd probably be better to compare numerically rather than with a regex.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd make sure that the user's input is formatted as a 5 digit number with leading zeroes, then the following regex would work:

```
^[0-9]{5}(?<!00000)$
```

This uses negative lookbehind to ensure that the string entered was not 5 zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Not nice but working:

from 1 to 99999: `[1-9][0-9]{0,4}`

from 01 to 09999: `0[1-9][0-9]{0,3}`

from 001 to 00999: `00[1-9][0-9]{0,2}`

from 0001 to 00099: `000[1-9][0-9]{0,1}`

from 00001 to 00009: `0000[1-9]`

And then putting all this together:

`^(0[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|00[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|000[1-9][0-9]{0,1}|0000[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{0,4})$`

Edit: updated.

Comment: finally it works. :) its just that the cases with leading zeros needs to be seperated.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really need to be a regular expression? Why not just check if `0 < value && value <=99999`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand, here the solution :
^[1-9][0-9]{0,4}$

Take all number between 1 and 99999

Why don't you use a RangeValidator it is simplier.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Value must be greater than zero." ControlToValidate="tbQty" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="99999" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: Um. No. I believe `09898` is fine too. And don't post multiple answers. Edit the existing one. And delete one of the invalid answers.

Comment: what about 001 - i think that should be valid, too.

Comment: thanks GeorgesD, it works but for inputs like 012. its not working. Can you pls fix this problem.